# Novo Google Sites - Incorporar HTML, Javascript e Google Planilhas

Tags: javascript, html, planilha, google-sites

Estou tentando usar o objeto "Incorporar" do novo Google Sites
Seleciono a opção "Incorporar Código"
e coloco o código abaixo e quando execultado aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:
"ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined"
Alguém conhece alguma alternativa que solucione este problema??
Obrigado

```
<head>
 <script>
   function funcaoLogar(){
     try{
      var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1y-hmm2qSJGzZ1M8kHD-ZF-....');
      var pasta = planilha.getSheetByName("DADOS");

      var pLogin = pasta.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
      var pSenha = pasta.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
     } catch (erro) {
          document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = erro;
        }

     var login = document.getElementById('fLogin').value;
     var senha = document.getElementById('fSenha').value;

     if(login == pLoguin && senha == pSenha){
         window.open('https://sites.google.com/view/perfil...';  
        }else {document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = "Login ou Senha errada";} 
  }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <p>Login: <input id="fLogin" type="text" value="">
 <p>Senha: <input type="password" id="fSenha" type="text" value="">
 <p><button type="button" onclick="funcaoLogar()">Logar</button>
 <p id="texto">
</body>
```

---

Comment: parece que voce precisa importar de alguma maneira a lib com a `SpreadsheetApp`, vou dar uma olhada e tambem e qualquer coisa te aviso

Comment: Para resolver Tentei simplificar o problema  criando no Google App Script o arquivo Código.gs com o código:

Answer (score 0):

Tentando simplificar o problema no Google App Script criei o arquivo Código.gs com o código abaixo:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('arquivoHTML');
}

function mostrarTexto(){
    //escreva aqui o seu código Google Script;
    return "Deu certo!!!!";
}
```

Criei o arquivo arquivoHTML.html com o código abaixo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
      function funcaoScript(){
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(retornoFuncao){
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = retornoFuncao;
            })
          .mostrarTexto();
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="funcaoScript()">Mostrar Resultado</button>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Ativei a API: Google Classroom API

quando eu testei utilizando o menu Publicar >> Implantar como aplicativo web... deu certo. Mas quando eu tentei incorporar no google sites apareceu "undefined"

Também tentei incorporar o  código html no próprio google sites e não aconteceu nada.

Talvez seja uma luz para a solução do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma
(explicação simplificada):

1 - Google Drive >> + Novo >> Mais >> Script do Google App; >> Criar e compartilhar

2 - Nomeie o projeto;

3 - Menu Arquivo >> Novo >> Arquivo HTML;

4 - Dê o nome para arquivo "arquivoHTML.html";

5 - No arquivo Código.gs inclua os códigos:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('arquivoHTML');
}

function funcaoLogar(login,senha){
      var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bsyvClx9sCy...');
      var pasta = planilha.getSheetByName("DADOS"); 
      var pLogin = pasta.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
      var pSenha = pasta.getRange(2, 3).getValue();
      if(login == pLogin && senha == pSenha){
       return  "window.open('https://sites.google.com/view/cibmalgo...')" ;  
        }else {
           return 'document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Login ou Senha errada"' ;
        }  
}
```

6 - No arquivo arquivoHTML.html inclua o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script> 
     function funcaoExecutar(){
       var login = document.getElementById('fLogin').value;
       var senha = document.getElementById('fSenha').value;

       google.script.run.withFailureHandler(error).withSuccessHandler(result).funcaoLogar(login,senha);  

       function result(result){
           eval(result);
       } 

       function error(message){
          document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = message;
       }
     }
    </script>
 <p>Login: <input id="fLogin" type="text"></p>
 <p>Senha: <input id="fSenha" type="password"></p>
 <p><button type="button" onclick="funcaoExecutar()">Logar</button></p>
 <p id="texto" style="color:red"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

7 - Selecione menu Recursos >> Serviços Avançados do Google...

8 - Procure "Google Classroom API" e Clique "desativado" para ativá-lo, ficará verde

9 - Logo abaixo tem uma caixa cinza escrita "Estes serviços também precisam ser ativados no Painel de APIs do Google Cloud Platform." clique sobre o texto azul

10 - clique em "+ ATIVAR APIS E SERVIÇOS"

11 - Pesquise por "Google Classroom API"

12 - Clique sobro o ícone que irá aparecer

13 - Clique em "Ativar"

14 - Volte para o Google App Script e clique em "OK"

Agora vamos fazer o teste

15 - Menu Publicar >> Implantar como Aplicativo da Web...

16 - Para: "Quem tem acesso ao aplicativo:" escolha a opção "Qualquer pessoa"

17 - Clique em "Atualizar"

18 - no texto "Teste o aplicativo da web para seu último código.", clique na parte azul e teste o código

se funcionar adequadamente copie a URL apresentada e clique "OK"

(lembrando que a cada atualização é importante colocar a versão e copiar a nova URL)

--->> INCORPORANDO O CÓDIGO AO GOOGLE SITES

19 - Google Drive >> + Novo >> Mais >> Google Sites

20 - Clique em "Incorporar"

21 - Por URL >> Cole a url copiada no Google Script

22 - Teste o site.

Solução dada por Maurílio Correia César do CBMGO